# Trouble overloading operators in C++ for dynamic array class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a C++ dynamic array class for my homework.  In my full code, I'm having issues with the operator overloading.  I've tried to pare it down to be simpler a thing to ask for someone's help fixing, and now I'm having trouble compiling and I'm pretty sure the issue is with my overloading of the array[] operators.

Can someone help me troubleshoot the compile error (and help me understand - if the actual output of main is different from my //expected outputs why that is)?

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class blarg
{
public:

    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, blarg&);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, blarg&);
        int operator=(int);
        int mine;
    blarg(void);
    ~blarg(void);
};

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "blarg.h"

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, blarg& nd)
{
    os << nd.mine;
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, blarg& nd)
{
    is >> nd.mine;
    return is;
}

int blarg::operator=(int a)
{
    mine = a;
    return mine;
}

blarg::blarg(void)
{
}


blarg::~blarg(void)
{
}

#pragma once
using namespace std;

class lightlist
{
public:
    blarg myBlarg;
    blarg& operator[](int);
    lightlist(void);
    ~lightlist(void);
};

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "lightlist.h"
#include "blarg.h"

blarg& lightlist::operator[](int param)
{
    return myBlarg;
}


lightlist::lightlist(void)
{
    myBlarg = new blarg;
    myBlarg.mine = 10;
}


lightlist::~lightlist(void)
{
}

int main()
{
    //in the full code this would create the linked list
    lightlist l = *new lightlist;
    //should output 10 because of the statement myBlarg.mine = 10
    cout << l[0] << endl;

    //should change myBlarg.mine to the inputted value
    cout << "Enter a value!" << endl;
    cin >> l[0];

    //should output the inputted value
    cout << l[0] << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Can you give a more precise account of your error messages?

Comment: They're at the line `blarg& lightlist::operator[](int param)`

Comment: @humanstory what's the actual message the compiler is giving you at that line? Without it we're just guessing.

Comment: 3 IntelliSense: declaration is incompatible with "<error-type> &lightlist::operator[](int)" 
(which references the line of code     `blarg& operator[](int);`)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is:

```
lightlist::lightlist(void) {
    myBlarg = new blarg;
    myBlarg.mine = 10;
}
```

Replace that with

```
lightlist::lightlist(void) {
    myBlarg.mine = 10;
}
```

and it compiles, and seemingly works.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out syntax errors in your constructor, but you say in the question that the error's on the `[]` operator instead:

```
#include "blarg.h"

blarg& lightlist::operator[](int param)
{
    return myBlarg;
}
```

There's nothing obviously wrong with this function signature, so I'd look for a syntax error (e.g. some unterminated statement) at the end of `blarg.h`. The compiler will often report such errors in the statement after they happen, which in this case is your `operator[]`.